# Display inner join result in php using pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this problem of displaying the order number, date, qty, valid and have inner join with name from validpersonel. how can i do this? i have my sample code below

```
include 'dbconnection.php';
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['id']; //companyid
$p_id = $_SESSION['pId']; //personnelid
//$id = $_GET['p_id']
try{
    $sql="Select 
            ordermain.OrderNo,
            ordermain.OrderDate,
            validpersonnel.Name,
            ordermain.OrderedQTY,
            ordermain.Valid
        FROM ordermain 
                INNER JOIN validpersonnel ON ordermain.PersonnelID=validpersonnel.PersonnelID 
        WHERE ordermain.CompanyID = :id";

    $res=$db->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute(array('id'=> $id));
    //$res = $db->query($sql);
}       
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('There was an error.');
}
    $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $res->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Just write a `foreach()` loop that iterates over `$result`.

Comment: var_dump($result) displays empty array @Barmar

Comment: then this is a problem with your **query**, not the way you are getting results.

Comment: That means the query didn't find any matching data.